# Expo React-Native Debugger - Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.cff11639.js` from ``

Tags: reactjs, expo, react-native

I'm just starting out with React-Native Expo with a blank app that is running fin in Android emulator. But I'm getting an error when trying to use react-native debugger from developer tools in Chrome.

I select "Debug Remote JS" from the Developer menu in Expo  [on the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe8K7.png) that opens this window in Chrome
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2NKr.png

From here soon as I open developer tools in chrome I get following error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/ui.bcd3f9d1.js` from ``: 

None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui\ui.bcd3f9d1.js(.native|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.wasm|.wasm)
  * debugger-ui\ui.bcd3f9d1.js\index(.native|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.wasm|.wasm)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Daniel\Projects.ReactNative\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Daniel\Projects.ReactNative\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Daniel\Projects.ReactNative\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at C:\Users\Daniel\Projects.ReactNative\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42   
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Daniel\Projects.ReactNative\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:841:41)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\Daniel\Projects.ReactNative\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (C:\Users\Daniel\Projects.ReactNative\MyApp\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:119:9)
```

Also get these warnings inside chrome console:

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui/ui.bcd3f9d1.js.map: HTTP error: status code 500, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui/ui.7beef9ab.css.map: HTTP error: status code 500, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.cff11639.js.map: HTTP error: status code 500, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

I've tried:

- Deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then `npm install`
- Empty Cache and Hard Reload in Chrome developer tools
- Clearing Expo cache, `expo r -c`
- reinstalling Expo on Android Virtual Device

Comment: Hey Daniel, did you find a solution for this issue? I'm running into a similar error with ejected Expo SDK 43.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```